# How to properly combine observables to post a tweet via button on Android?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable

Have a simple rx question - I am very new to a whole concept :(
Basically, I have some data which I want to post as a tweet via pressing a button. How to properly combine observables?
Here is the snippet:

```
_disposables.add(
    Observable.combineLatest(
        ObservableClickable.toObservable(_binding.btnPost),
        _model.getUrls(),
        _model.getImages(),
        _model.getHashtags(),
        (click, urls, images, hashtags) -> {
            Toast.makeText(_activity, "Posting tweet!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        })
        .subscribe()
);
```

First one is the event from my button and the latter ones are the values which I want to include with the tweet.

toObservable call:

```
@NonNull public static Observable<Object> toObservable(@NonNull View view)
{
    return Observable.create(e -> view.setOnClickListener(v -> e.onNext(new Object())));
}
```

Part of my observable list implementation:

```
public class ObservableList <T> implements List<T>
{
    private final List<T> _source;
    private final PublishSubject<List<T>> _subject = PublishSubject.create();

    public ObservableList(@NonNull List<T> source)
    {
        _source = source;
        _subject.onNext(_source);
    }

    @NonNull public Observable<List<T>> getObservable() { return _subject; }
...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does model.get~~() return the Observable?

Answer (score 0):

### combineLastest

At first, model.get~~() must return Observable.

And `combineFunction` should not relate action.

You'd better think `combineFunction` is `map`'s argument.

So, this is code I changed

```
_disposables.add(
    Observable.combineLatest(
        ObservableClickable.toObservable(_binding.btnPost),
        _model.getUrls(),
        _model.getImages(),
        _model.getHashtags(),
        (click, urls, images, hashtags) -> new Post(urls, images, hashtags))
    .subscribe(post => Toast.makeText(_activity, "Posting tweet!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show())
);
```

Reference: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#combineLatest(java.util.List,%20rx.functions.FuncN)

### observable list

I think observable list emit not a list, but items in list.

So how about using `Observable.from(Iterable)`

```
Observable.from(list) // => it emits item by item
```

Refer to http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#from(java.lang.Iterable)

### getObservable()

You'd better avoid pass subject as subject.

Subject is Bi-directional.

So, pass subject as observable. Use `subject.asObservable()`

Refer to http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#asObservable()

Answer (score 0):

### Combining or composing Observables

- combine latest is not related exactly to what you want to achieve,    what you want to do is to **compose** `Observable`s together to    create meaningful chain ("stream") of events.
- In this particular case, you should start from the clicks    `Observable` and react to each click, let's assume that each model    method (get___) returns Observable (I'll touch this point later),    then you want to transform clicks events to `Observable` that fetch    the model data, for that use `flatMap()`, and create an `Observable`    to fetch the model data, as you depend on all of the model data, you    want to use `zip()` which (like a zipper...) will wait for all model    data to emit value and then will emit it as one event with all the    data from all the `Observables` that were zipped together.
  With    this new Observable that represent generated tweet data in response    to click, you might want to perform the tweet posting, which is    probably (?) a query to server, so you can continue on and compose    the network call in the chain (either by another `flatMap()` if you    have already Observable that do the network request or by `map()`    that will take the fetched combined data for tweet and perform the    request, to sum it up something like this:

  ```
  ObservableClickable.toObservable(_binding.btnPost)
              .flatMap(aVoid -> Observable.zip( _model.getUrls(), _model.getImages(), _model.getHashtags(), 
                      (urls, images, hashTags) -> createTweetObject(urls, images,hashTags)))
              .map(tweet -> postTweet(tweet))
              .subscribe();
  ```

### Some comments on the code:

- It is not very clear, but it's seems that you transform each model
  member to `Observable` using your `ObservableList`, you should not do
  this, unless you this data is getting loaded in async fashion, which 
  seems it is not, according to your `ObservableList` implementation,
  in this case you have already the data in memory ready, bear in mind that    ReactiveX is for reacting to events and collections of values **over 
  time** (async).
  so if we getting back to the example above, just map each click to tweet object:

  ```
   ObservableClickable.toObservable(_binding.btnPost)
          .map(aVoid -> {
              Tweet tweet = createTweetObject(_model.getUrls(),     _model.getImages(),_model.getHashtags());
              return postTweet(tweet);
          })
          .subscribe();
  ```
- besides, before you're using `Subject` check if there is some
  operator. creating `Observable` to emit in memory objects can be done
  using `Observable.just()`, or `Observable.from()`
- Creating `Observable` for wrapping clicks (or any other existing async api) - should be done cautiously, you can read [here](https://medium.com/yammer-engineering/converting-callback-async-calls-to-rxjava-ebc68bde5831#.99g3ofxus), and also, you can use [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) library that already done it for many UI elements in Android